# wrong redirection of command to shell variable?

Tags: shell

I want to get directory names from a XML stdin and then copy the content to  targetdirectory:

```
 count=$(echo $xmlstring | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//directory)" -) && for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)); do {currentpath=$(echo $xmlstring| xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//directory[$i]/text()" -) && cp currentpath /opt/targetdir} ; done
```

getting error :

> syntax error near unexpected token `echo'

when I use `echo` instead of `cp`:

```
count=$(echo $xmlstring | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//directory)" -) && for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)); do {currentpath=$(echo $xmlstring| xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//directory[$i]/text()" -) && echo currentpath} ; done
```

Basically i am trying to get the directory names in the xml Stdin as source directories for my CP command....so that in the end , all the files from the directories specified in the xml are copied to targetdir

I get error:

```
-bash: {currentpath=/opt/in1: No such file or directory
{currentpath=: command not found
```

fetching directory from a xml stdin and writing into a txt file works,
but when I want to copy from currentdirectory to some targetdir it does not work.

Comment: i tried $ , it does not work either....i need to use a oneliner because of the system i am working with

Comment: I'm guessing you have cut-and-paste errors, because `$currentpath=` is not a good way to assign a variable and omitting a `$` on the rhs of `var=$(...)` is also bad.  Or are those the root problems you're facing?

Comment: sorry, typos there,,,,i edited the original post

Comment: One of your errors is because of a missing space.  bash is picky and you cannot write `{cmd` without a space after the `{`.

Comment: `{` is an ambiguous syntax feature. You need spaces around them and a semicolon before `}` to make a list. `{ echo a; echo b; echo c; }` vs. `(echo a; echo b; echo c)`.

Comment: Given XML's pervasive usage especially of `<`, `>` and `=`, you *must* quote your `$xmlstring` everywhere you use it, like this: `echo "$xmlstring" ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of mistakes, see this corrected version :

```
count=$(echo "$xmlstring" | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//directory)" -)
for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)); do
    currentpath="$(
        echo "$xmlstring" |
            xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//directory[$i]/text()" - |
            tr -d '$\n'
    )"
    cp "$currentpath" "/opt/targetdir/"
done
```

Comment: worked thanks, there was a problem with the xpath query itself,,,,THANKS A LOT!!!!

Comment: would it be possible to use SCP to a remote server here?